# ts-node cannot find dependent module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node

Assume to have simple typescript program having two files:

src/hello.js

```js
export default function hello() {
  return 'Hello world'
}
```

src/say.js

```js
import hello from './hello.js'
console.log(hello())
```

with the following tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2023"],
    "module": "node16",
    "target": "es2022",

    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node16",

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

and CommonJS type set in package.json

```json
{
  "type": "commonjs"
}
```

The problem is with `ts-node` failing with the following error:

```
$ npx ts-node src/say.ts
Error: Cannot find module './hello.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/pawel/wrk/github/ts-sandbox/src/say.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/pawel/wrk/github/ts-sandbox/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pawel/wrk/github/ts-sandbox/src/say.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/pawel/wrk/github/ts-sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/pawel/wrk/github/ts-sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/pawel/wrk/github/ts-sandbox/src/say.ts' ]
}
```

This project works well when transpiled with `tsc` and simply run `node dist/say.js`. Also `ts-node` alternatives (`tsx src/say.ts`, `tsimp src/say.ts`) work without issues.

Please find complete source code [here](https://github.com/pawel-id/ts-sandbox).

What I'm missing with `ts-node` please?

Comment: What happens if you run `npx ts-node say.ts` from within the `src` directory?

Comment: @PatrickGorman running `npx ts-node say.ts` from `src` yields the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try removing the `.js` extension from the import line:

src/say.js

```
import hello from './hello.js' // <<< HERE
console.log(hello())
```

Comment: thanks @luís-poze this is so simple workaround. Indeed it works without extensions.

However I feel this should work with .js extension and ts-node does it wrong. The .js extension is allowed in CommonJS (our target module system) and also used in typescript reference https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html . Also tsc compiler does the job with .js extension.

Comment: I see. Please have a look at this issue, [#738](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/783) in the [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) repository.

Comment: In fact, using the `.js` extension appears not be supported due to the build-on-demand nature of ts-node.
Maybe is not your case but If you simple compile your code with tsc it will work with `.js`.
You still can use `.ts` extension, but If you really need,  you can try using some compile time transformer, like [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript) or [ts-patch](https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch) (for typescript greater than 5.0) to transform the code before the build.